# How to combine / nest CALayer masks?

Tags: swift, uiview, calayer

Is it possible use nested `CALayer` mask to create one combined mask? My goal is to create a complex shapes by combining / masking other complex shapes and applying a gradient to the result.

For example one `CAShapeLayer` my hold a path which draws a unicorn head and a second `CAShapeLayer` my hold a path which draws a flower. By applying the flower layer as mask to the unicorn layer, I get a "flowerly unicorn". In then next step I could than apply this complex shape to a `CAGradientLayer` to get a "flowerly unicorn rainbow".

However, when applying the unicorn layer (with the flower mask) as mask for the gradient, the result is a unicorn rainbow. The flower mask already applied to the unicorn is skipped.

Is there any other way to combine / nest layer mask to create such shapes?

---

The following code illustrates the problem using some simpler shapes:

```
let rectLayer = CAShapeLayer()
rectLayer = // ... a simple rect shape

let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
circleLayer = // ... a circle shape, half overlapping the rect

// Apply rect as mask to create half circle
circleLayer.mask = rectLayer

// Some gradient
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer = // ... set up gradient with some colors

// Apply masked circle as mask to get a half circle with gradient
gradientLayer.mask = circleLayer
```

Now I would assume to get a half circle shape with a gradient. However, I get a circle with a gradient instead. It seem that when applying the `circleLayer` as mask to the `gradientLayer` the rect mask is not considered / applied...

Am I doing something wrong? Is there another way to solve this? Masking and combining masks is quite a common task in many different applications. Thus I wonder if such a powerful framework as CA has a way of doing this.

Comment: I found out, that it is not possible to nest mask in this specific way. This does not mean that there might not other way to do this. Maybe I am just doing it the wrong way? Masking is a quite common task in a lot of different applications. Thus it seems to very likely that such a powerfull framework like Core Animation has a way to to this...

Comment: "How can this be solved?" How can what be solved? What's the goal? This has all the hallmarks of an xy question... I _think_ you're after a semicircle filled with a gradient; that's easy enough. But then don't ask about nested masks, ask about the semicircle with a gradient.

Comment: "I found out, that it is not possible to nest mask in this specific way. This does not mean that there might not other way to do this." That's right, and that's what makes this an xy question. Do you know what that is? https://xyproblem.info The way you propose to do this is particularly troublesome given the fact that simply drawing a semicircle (without using a mask to help) is trivial.

Comment: I fully understand what you are trying to say. However, I think the problem and goal are clearly described in my question: Combining multiple mask to create a complex shapes with gradients. Of course the semicircle is just one example. As now edited creating a flower-unicorn-rainbow is another, more complex one.

Comment: But masking is not how to create a complex shape. And despite a very long life I have never see a flower-unicorn-rainbow. So again, I am at a loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @DuncanC pointed out mask cannot be nested. So, applying Layer A as mask to Layer B and than applying Layer B as mask to Layer C does not work as expected. This will only use the original content of B as mask and not taking account the changed made by Layer A.

I was able to get around this limitation by first "flattening" the result of Layer B + Mask Layer A. This is done by creating an image of this result and than applying this as mask to Layer C:

```
let layerA = CAShapeLayer() // ... add some shapes
let layerB = CAShapeLayer() // ... add some shapes

// Apply A as mask to B
layerB.mask = layerA

// Flatten B
let flatB = layerB.flatten()

// Apply flatB as mask to C
let layerC = CAShapeLayer() // ... add some shapes
layerC.mask = flatB
```

The flattening is done using this CALayer extension:

```
extension CALayer {
    func flatten() -> CALayer {
        guard let colorSpace = CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB),
              let ctx = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(bounds.width), height: Int(bounds.height), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 4*Int(bounds.width), space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue) else { return CALayer() }
    
        ctx.translateBy(x: 0, y: bounds.height)
        ctx.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

        render(in: ctx)
        let image = ctx.makeImage()
    
        let flattenedLayer = CALayer()
        flattenedLayer.frame = frame
        flattenedLayer.contents = image
    
        return flattenedLayer
    }
}
```

This might not be the perfect solution but it works very well in my case. Maybe this might help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: You can't nest masks. You will need ot create a unique mask for each layer that masks the parts of that layer that you want to hide.

Comment: Ok, I understand mask cannot be nested. But the rest of your answer sound as if mask could still be used to solved the situation I described by combining / applying masks in a different way? Is that correct? Can a gradient half circle be created using masks or does this require other custom drawing techniques?

Comment: A gradient half-circle? You mean a radial gradient where half of it is masked? Sure. You can always apply an arbitrarily shaped mask to any single layer. Create a half-circle shape as a shape layer, and apply that as a mask to your radial gradient layer.